# Dockerized Localstack EMR step creation syntax

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, localstack

I am trying to run some applications in localstack on Mac OS. I am able to create a cluster but have some issues configuring steps.

Ideally I want to use JSON to configure my steps. When I run

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-some-cluster --steps '[{"Name": "hello world","ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE","Jar": "s3://hello-world.jar","Properties": "","Args": ["foo"],"Type": "CUSTOM_JAR"}]'
```

my step creates and EMR is happy

```
{
    "StepIds": [
        "s-some-step-id"
    ]
}
```

However when I run the same command against my localstack

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 emr add-steps --cluster-id j-some-cluster --steps '[{"Name": "hello world","ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE","Jar": "s3://hello-world.jar","Properties": "","Args": ["foo"],"Type": "CUSTOM_JAR"}]'
```

I get the following error -

> An error occurred (InternalError) when calling the AddJobFlowSteps operation (reached max retries: 2): exception while calling emr.AddJobFlowSteps: FakeStep.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hadoop_jar_step._properties.member.1._key'

I can also create my step on localstack using the other syntax -

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 emr add-steps --cluster-id j-localstack-cluster-id --steps 'Type=CUSTOM_JAR,Name="hello world",ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,Jar=s3://hello-world.jar,Args=["foo"]'
```

So it seems like localstack just doesn't like JSON for some reason, which is not ideal. Any ideas how to get it to work?

EDIT: there is also nothing obvious in the wall of text that docker spits out. This is the only relevant line I get -

```
uruyqbsgy7un-localstack-1            | 2023-04-28T17:32:04.934 ERROR --- [   asgi_gw_6] l.aws.handlers.logging     : exception during call chain: FakeStep.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hadoop_jar_step._properties.member.1._key'
```

Comment: this issue was apparently specific to localstack versions 2.x.x and is fixed after 3.0.0